# How can I use SMTP and Gmail in an end user application?

Tags: security, smtp, gmail

I am working on an application that requires communication via email with the user and the client for whom the application is being developed.
Basically the flow is thus :

- Program Does Something
- Program sends an email detailing if it worked or not to the user and my client

We have established a Gmail account to make this happen. Unfortunately my clients users are multinational and Gmail freaked out and started blocking users, which started throwing exceptions when they were trying to use the program.

In the emails I saw when I checked the account, I saw I see at least two of these emails that say "Suspicious sign in prevented", and there was a red bar that said multiple attempts were tried to sign in and asked if it was me, and there were points all over the world.

How would I go about making it so that Gmail doesn't freak out when it sees users trying to sign in all over the planet?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't sending through a some kind of a server application not an option? I.e. instead of making SMTP connection from your end user app directly to Gmail server your app sends a request to your web server which does actual SMTP connection. This way you'll also eliminate issues when SMTP ports are blocked on end users' machines.

Comment: Okay, but what if I don't have a web server, and I really don't know how to do what you are saying here; can you provide a link or an example?

Comment: Perhaps, some proxy services exist which allow you to send to gmail without your own wen server but I'm only aware of scenarios where you need your own web server (I can be just an account on a shared hosting, no need to have a dedicated server). What kind of a server platform (PHP, ASP.NET, etc) is easier for you to use? I can suggest you something only in case of ASP.NET as I'm myself a developer of mail component for ASP.NET (.NET in general).

Comment: It's a desktop application, not a web application. I'm just using C# .Net WinForms/WPF

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's a desktop app, but we're talking about moving some logic from your desktop app to a web app - so that all sendings to Gmail would occur from the same location. And from this point of view it can be easier for you to use the same language for your server app (i.e. asp.net with c# and not PHP, Phyton or Ruby, for instance). .Net comes with a simple email sending component, an example for Gmail can be found at: http://forums.asp.net/t/1817561.aspx?Sending+email+through+Web+Service+asmx+ Should you need something more advanced, you can use paid third-party components.